# Make mac OS forget all settings and window positions related to smplayer

Tags: macos, macos-bigsur

i want mac os to forget the windows position and changed settings in smplayer and reset them to default. How can i do it ? is there any universal way (that works on all most apps) ?

Thx in advance !

Answer (score -1):

The 'simplest' way, rather than search half the Library for where any particular app might save prefs or positions would be to just uninstall it using [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) (Freeware)

This will work for any app that was installed by just dragging it to the global Applications folder & not for apps that needed a full installer.

After that, just 'install' it again by dragging a fresh copy to Applications. If you don't have a .dmg file right there, you can cheat this by just copying the old one to your Desktop before running AppCleaner, then drag it back after you uninstalled.

Answer (score -1):

Typically apps store data under /Users/**user name**/Library/Application Support/ or /Users/**user name**/Library/Application Support/**app name**/

Look for a .prefs file or a directory with the app name and delete it.